# Strange java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, exception

I have this line of code:

```
    if (gram.getVN().get(i) != gram.getAxiom() && 
lr1.getAutoma()[j][lr1.getColumn().indexOf(gram.getVN().get(i))].size() != 0) {
 //some actions

}
```

and it works fine. But if I do this:

```
System.out.println(lr1.getAutoma()[j][lr1.getColumn().indexOf(gram.getVN().get(i))].size());

        if (gram.getVN().get(i) != gram.getAxiom() && 
    lr1.getAutoma()[j][lr1.getColumn().indexOf(gram.getVN().get(i))].size() != 0) {
     //some actions

}
```

then I get that exception, and i can't understand why! Can anyone help me? Thank you..

Comment: Well *where* do you get the exception? And can you simplify the example? (There are huge numbers of things we no nothing about in this code.) Note that in your first case, if the first expression (`gram.getVN().get(i) != gram.getAxiom()`) evaluates to `false`, then it *won't* evaluate the second expression - whereas in your second case, you're printing out that second expression regardless.

Comment: What's the value of `j`? How about `lr1.getColumn().indexOf(gram.getVN().get(i))`? The error message pretty much explains the problem: you're using an array index, -1, which is out of bounds (since all array indexes must be >= 0). Incidentally, you may want to consider a temp variable here and there -- inlining everything can make it hard to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because `lr1.getColumn().indexOf(gram.getVN().get(i))` returns -1.

In the first snippet, this part is not even executed because `&&` is a short-circuit operator, and the first condition (`gram.getVN().get(i) != gram.getAxiom()`) is false.

Comment: You're right. I've inserted more prints to see the values of the first and the second operator of the AND and i get you result. Thanks